# IFS Formula not going past three conditions/value ranges

Tags: google-sheets, ifs

Sorry, I am new to this and can't seem to work a formula out. I have written an `IFS` formula basically saying hat if the value in a cell is a particular number, than the value of the next cell references a cell from another page (in the same workbook) and will fill that cell accordingly. The problem is that I have three cells to reference from but it won't recognize anything over two conditions/values.

Posts 100x100   17  2.1 *$5,555.00*

> =IFS(C5=2.4,'Price Input'!B2,2.1,'Price Input'!B3,1.8,'Price Input'!B4)

Above formula is a table where c5 = $5555.00
and a table on another page, b2,b3,b4.

It references from the first two without a problem. I've tried changing the order of the values, and the same this happens, it won't read the third condition in the sequence. It will however read the second option regardless of either of the last two conditions.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Your `IFS` formula does not appear to be constructed properly.  I don't entirely know what you are trying to achieve without seeing an example, but you might try:

> =IFS(C5=2.4,'Price Input'!B2,C5=2.1,'Price Input'!B3,C5=1.8,'Price Input'!B4)